# Diffeomorphisms and connections

Tags: differential-geometry, connections, diffeomorphism

Consider a hypersurface in $\mathbb{R}^d$ with some connection (Levi-Civita if necessary). Does there exist some diffeomorphism into another hypersurface of $\mathbb{R}^d$ so that the mapped connection is the Levi-Civita connection induced by the Euclidean metric? How would one in principle find such a diffeomorphism?

Comment: The first obstruction to this would be the fact that not every affine connection is torsion-free, but the Levi-Cevita connection is necessarily torsion-free. So in general, we can not do this for a generic affine connection.

Comment: That's true, but if we assume that the connection in original hypersurface is the Levi-Cevita connection of some Riemann metric (not necessary the induced Euclidean metric) on the hypersurface, then the original connection would be torsion free.

Comment: @J.V.Gaiter I don't think this has to be the case, see for example [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/362234).